# Python: Child Class Does not Specify all Args of Parent Abstract Method?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, abstract

This might be a naive question, but I was wondering about the purpose of (both positional and keyword) arguments in a python function. For example:

```py
from abc import ABC

class NeuralInference(ABC): 
    def __init__(self) -> None: 
        pass 
    
    @abstractmethod
    def train(self, training_batch_size: int): 
        raise NotImplementedError


class RatioEstimator(NeuralInference): 
    def __init__(self) -> None: 
        super().__init__()
    
    def train(self, wandb_flag: bool = False) -> None: 
        print(f"wandb_flag: {wandb_flag}")

ratio_estimator = RatioEstimator().train()
```

Now, this code is running, but I would *have expected a bug*, since `RatioEstimator`, which inherits from `NeuralInference`, does not have the argument `training_batch_size` specified. Could sb please explain why this is okay for Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABC only cares if the derived class overrides all `abstractethods`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or is derived from it. A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden...

Your `RatioEstimator` class overrides the `train` method, so you have fulfilled the `abstractmethod` contract.